# MySQL: умный GROUP BY

Tags: sql, mysql

Здравствуйте, коллеги.

Есть таблица:

```
id(int)|categories(varchar)
1|5
2|1
3|6
4|2,4
5|2
6|3
7|4
```

Запрос: SELECT `categories`, COUNT(*) as `count` FROM `table` GROUP BY `categories` ORDER BY `categories`

```
categories|count
1|2
2|1
2,4|1
4|1
5|1
6|1
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добыть подобные данные:

```
categories|count
1|2
2|2
4|2
5|1
6|1
```

Благодарю за ответы.

С уважением.

Comment: Сменить проектировщика, который придумал хранить категории в таком виде :)

Comment: На будущее, в каком виде категории лучше хранить?

Comment: Не нужно ничего изобретать, самый что ни на есть стандартный вид годится: `cat_id int primary key, name varchar, ...`

Comment: С помощью поля int не сделать мультикатегорий. categories REGEXP '[[:<:]](2)[[:>:]]'

Comment: @universal_mind, таблица `categories` явно не висит в воздухе. Связь между ней и сущностями, которые принадлежат категориям, делается отдельной таблицей. Но если задание хитровывернуто, или есть какие-то отдельные требования, то они не обозначены в посте, поэтому дальше уже - гадания и подземный стук.

Comment: Ваши таблицы находятся в нулевой нормальной форме. Согласен с @klopp: так жить нельзя. Повысьте нормальность БД и квалификацию программиста.

Comment: умный груп бай для глупой структуры, клево.

Answer (score 1):

Если категорий меньше 10, их можно [нагенерить](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_number_sequence_generation.html). Тогда решение может быть такое:

```
select q, count(*) from T join
(select '1' q union all select '2' union all select '3' union all select '4' union all select '5' union all select '6' ) num
on categories like concat('%',q,'%')
group by q;
```

Если больше 10, нужно парсить строку.